# Android: How to understand layouts?

Tags: android-studio, tablelayout

I am struggling big time with trying to make a simple layout with two TextView:s under each other on the left and corresponding two TimePicker:s under each other on the right. However, whichever view I use or attributes I choose that seem relevant I do not get the desired outcome. Here is my current try:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/text_start_time"
            android:text="@string/start_time"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker_start"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        >
        <TextView
            android:layout_column="1"
            android:id="@+id/text_end_time"
            android:text="@string/end_time"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            />
        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker_end"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow>
        <Button
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/button_calculate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="calculateWorkingTime"
            />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

This gives the following output

[Where is "Start"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFuut.png)

As you can see "Start" is not even shown! I would like to align "Start" with the vertical center of the TimePicker spinner. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

First, don't use a TableLayout. Use Linears, as you are a beginner and they're easier to use and understand. Here's what you should do:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_start_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/start_time"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker_start"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
     </LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_end_time"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/end_time"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            />

        <TimePicker
            android:id="@+id/time_picker_end"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:timePickerMode="spinner"
            android:layout_marginTop="-25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
            android:layout_column="2"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/button_calculate"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="calculateWorkingTime"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
```

What I've done is creating a Linear Layout and, into it, another two with orientation:horizontal, which makes the elements appear one next to each other.
Also, I've put width and height to all the elements, what is very important.
I've put wrap_content, if you want to change it, no problem.

I didn't test it, if there's any error, just coment

Hope it helps!